# Jquery Multiselect doesn't scroll to selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, multi-select

I'm using JQuery Multiselect plugin from here: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

When the list of options is long a scroll appears, but it doesn't scroll automatically to the selected option. It means that, after selecting the 50th option, if I want to select option 51st I have to search again all the way down.

Do you know how to solve this issue? I tried to use scrolltTop but no luck.

The code is really simple...

```
$(function(){
   $("select").multiselect({multiple: false, selectedList: 1});
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/g5r92/1/

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this, first attempt and it´s working fine

http://jsfiddle.net/g5r92/7/

```
 $(function(){
   $("select").multiselect({multiple: false, selectedList: 1});
   $('.ui-multiselect').click(function(){

      $('.ui-multiselect-checkboxes').animate({
         scrollTop: $(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes .ui-state-active").offset().top
      }, 2000);
   });    

  });
```

you will only need to fit it to your needs, add some extra pixels to the offset and it will scroll the selected option in the middle instead of the very top

Comment: You are right, it works indeed. My problem was because I have more than one multiselect in the same page, so when offset().top was always zero for any multiselect except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it works indeed. My problem was because I have more than one multiselect in the same page, so offset().top was always zero for any multiselect except the first one (and I hadn't noticed that it was not zero for the first one...). Solved with this:

```
$('.ui-multiselect-checkboxes').scrollTop($($('.ui-multiselect-checkboxes .ui-state-active')[index]).offset().top);
```

Where index is the index of multiselects in the page.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, to edit your "jQuery MultiSelect UI Widget **1.12**" JS file,
to "auto-select" while opening the menu option.

**on your file, search for:  (always select first item)**
`this.labels.eq(0).trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseenter').find('input').trigger('focus');`

**and change it to: (dynamic select):**

`var idxSelected = 0;
if (o.multiple == true){
            // find first checked.
            idxSelected = $container.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked:first').parent().parent().index();
}

else {
            // find the one that checked
            idxSelected = $container.find('.ui-state-active:first').parent().index();
}
idxSelected = idxSelected < 0 ? 0 : idxSelected ;
this.labels.eq(idxSelected).trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseenter').find('input').trigger('focus');`

**tested on FF + CHROME + IE (on multiple + single list)**